# curl PUT returns HTTP/1/1 403 forbidden Authentication required though passing the creds

Tags: rest, curl, gerrit

i'm trying gerrit REST API via curl. it returns me HTTP/1.1 403 forbidden error (im passing the credentials in curl)
The GET works without credentials. Appreciate response.
Thanks alot

OS :- Ubuntu 17.10
curl version :- curl 7.55.1

```
curl -v -X PUT --user admin:<password> -H "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" http://john-lenovo-b460e:8080/changes/ELK_PROJECT~master~I75da52cf1c7a40997afa92202f079d05c514ba65/
```

the above code returns the below o/p
Trying 127.0.1.1...

```
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to john-lenovo-b460e (127.0.1.1) port 8080 (#0)
Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
PUT /changes/ELK_PROJECT~master~I75da52cf1c7a40997afa92202f079d05c514ba65/ HTTP/1.1
Host: john-lenovo-b460e:8080
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46TXhxSlk5Um5pd3VYbnJKR2FteHFVUUZ5VFJvUzlMcitJZ09DMXdZQjJR
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 11:12:28 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 24

Authentication required
* Connection #0 to host john-lenovo-b460e left intact
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? AFAIK there's no "PUT /changes/{change-id}" endpoint.

Comment: It was mentioned in Gerrit document.                             
 Set Commit Message
'PUT /changes/{change-id}/message'

Answer (score 0):

To set a new commit message (creating a new patchset) in a change, you need to execute the following command:

```
curl -v -X PUT --user admin:<password> --data @- -H "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" http://john-lenovo-b460e:8080/changes/ELK_PROJECT~master~I75da52cf1c7a40997afa92202f079d05c514ba65/message <<EOF
{
    "message": "<new_commit_message>\n\nChange-Id: I75da52cf1c7a40997afa92202f079d05c514ba65\n"
}
EOF
```

Comment: Hi Marcelo, Im getting the same Error "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"

Comment: It seems the user (admin) doesn't have permission to create a new patchset.